# Linear layout below the ListView, Some portions not visible?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with LinearLayout which is below the listview. I tried to give the listview weight and layout above, set the layout_height to 0dp but nothing wotked.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="#00c4ff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application № - "
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="__"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Comment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save and close"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

when ListView fills the screen, I cannot see the buttons below to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="#00c4ff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application № - "
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="__"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
            android:layout_weight="30" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Comment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save and close"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please also explain how you have fixed the issue. Code only answers are not as helpful.

Comment: The Approach Layout-weight and Weight-Sum is the solution for this question. but before asking such questions please try, and don't ask such direct questions

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="#00c4ff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application № - "
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="__"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
android:alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Comment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save and close"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout">
            </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Have edited your code. Try this.

Here in this I have used `RelativeLayout`, so that we use `android:alignParentBottom="true"` for bottom layout which makes the layout in fix in bottom. Simillarly we can do for top layout using `android:alignParentBottom="true"`. Now coming to `ListView`, which we need to place between top and bottom layout I have used the following code to achieve it

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
```

This makes the `ListView` to stick in between the top and bottom layout.

Hope this is helpful:)

Comment: Please also explain how you have fixed the issue. Code only answers are not as helpful.

Comment: @Doomsknight: Look I have given the explanation for the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Your layout edited by adding layout weights. Please check.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="0dp"
                  android:layout_weight="0.1"
                  android:weightSum="100"
                  android:background="#00c4ff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application № - "
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="__"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Comment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save and close"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried your code and it didn`t work, I cant see the listview at all

Answer (score 1):

You should try List View with Layout having weight.

Sample Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
       />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
      >
 <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this your height is fixed for listview. Assuming that you can use list view as srollable in particular height.

Comment: Thank you but it didn`t work, now I cant see the listview at all

Answer (score 0):

Change  as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00c4ff">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Application № - "
            android:layout_weight="50"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="__"
            android:layout_weight="20" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:hint="dd/mm/yyyy"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/ll">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Comment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Send" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save and close"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please also explain how you have fixed the issue. Code only answers are not as helpful.